# How can I get all Destiny 2 expansions?

Tags: ps4, destiny-2

I pre-ordered the Destiny 2: Shadowkeep game for $35 and I got the base Destiny 2 game with the year 1 expansion packs -- Warmind and Curse of Osiris. I will be getting the Shadowkeep DLC later on when it comes out and I will get its expansion pass later on when it actually arrives.

My question is: Can I buy the Forsaken DLC with its 2 expansions now? I can't see it on the store at all, only the $100 edition which also includes the base game. Do I have to buy this edition to get Forsaken? I don't want to have to pay for another copy of the base game.

Comment: For PC or PS 4?

Comment: The base game will be free to play with Shadowkeep

Comment: For ps4, and i do have the base game now they gave it to me but i cant get forsaken its not on the store, the only thing on the store is the 100$ forsaken edition with the base game and 2 expansions which i own currently from shadowkeep so how will i get forsaken?

Comment: Forsaken content will only unlock once you've completed the Red War, Curse of Osiris and Warmind campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

This has been covered off in this weeks [(6/13/2019) This Week At Bungie](https://www.bungie.net/en/Explore/Detail/News/47928).

Specifically,

> Forsaken and New Light
>   Q: Will Destiny 2: New Light be its own separate game/file?
>   A: No. All Destiny 2 players will be automatically
>   converted to New Light and will maintain all of their prior purchases
>   and entitlements.
>
> Q: What Forsaken and Forsaken Annual Pass content will be included in
>   New Light?
>   A: Forsaken content available in Destiny 2: New Light
>   includes: Free roam on all destinations, Strikes playlists, Crucible
>   playlists, Gambit and Gambit Prime playlists, Select Annual Pass content
>
> Q: What Forsaken and Forsaken Annual Pass content will NOT be included
>   in New Light?
>   A: Forsaken content available only with purchase
>   includes: The Forsaken campaign, Year 2 raids, and dungeons Exotic
>   quests

So you'll only need to purchase Forsaken if you'd like to play the Forsaken campaign, dungeons and acquire Forsaken exotic items.